# find number of NSArray object on string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I would like to count my NSArray object of my NSString. My NSArray has `@"a"`, `@"w"` objects, and my string is `@"abcdefgw"`. I would like to know how many times the `@"w"` object is there in my string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can get the number of objects in an array by sending it a `count` message. You can get the number of characters in a string by sending it a `length` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator`, though this may have boundary issues. You can also use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` like this:

```
NSString *shortString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"w" withString:@""];
return mystring.length-shortString.length;
```

Comment: I like that, but you will have to divide by the search strings length if you allow multi char searches.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to count substrings you will have to search for substrings then shrink the range each time... something like.

```
-(NSInteger)occurrencesOfSubstring:(NSString *)substring inString:(NSString *)string
{
    int occurrences =0;

    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [string length]);
    NSRange foundRange;
    do {
        foundRange = [string rangeOfString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];
        if ((foundRange.location != NSNotFound)) {
            occurrences++;
            searchRange.location = foundRange.location+foundRange.length;
            searchRange.length = [string length] - (foundRange.location+foundRange.length);
        }
    }while (foundRange.location != NSNotFound);    

    return occurrences;
}
```

Comment: This is **very** slow. It would be faster just to run through the string and check each character to avoid the overhead of `NSRange`.

Comment: why do you expect a scalar type to be slow? did you profile it?

Comment: Yes. For me, using `rangeOfString` repeatedly was about 50% slower than just reading each character. This was several months and at least one iOS update ago, so it's possible the performance is much improved now. For such a simple example, I doubt it makes a difference. But if this needs to be called repeatedly, it may get costly.

Comment: Good to know. If I get some time I may look at it, just out of curiosity.